# Is it possible to embed github gists in wordpress comments?

Tags: comments

Is it possible to embed github gists in wordpress comments, I have seen a few plugins which allow embedding gists in posts, but not yet seen any plugins that allow embedding gists in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, oembed doesn't run on comments by default, but you can make it by using this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oembed-for-comments/

It uses WordPress' internal oembed classes so if your posts support gists then so will your comments